# ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.1 when creating AIR iOS package with native extension

Tags: ios, mobile, air, air-native-extension, libgcc

I'm trying to create an AIR native extension for iOS, but when try create the package to deploy to my device, I'm getting the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.1
Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

Its working when I try to create the app for the simulator.  I've tried many combinations of adding libgcc_s.1 to my platform.xml file, creating just a package for iOS, creating a fat binary for both the simulator and the phone, etc.

I'm not sure why it needs the libgcc_s.1 package since I'm not referencing it in my extension.  I tried adding it manually to the "Link Binary With Libraries" list in xcode, and at that point it won't build, telling me that libgcc_s.1.dylib doesn't exist on my system.

Do other people have this lib on their system?  Does anybody know why it's being added if I didn't ask for it?

Comment: Did you manage to get it fixed? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I finally solved this after days of searching and testing. Remove the -platformsdk option when packaging for device.

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ, goto project structure -> modules - >iOs -> delete Apple iOS SDK -> apply -> compile on device )